# Ionic / OneSignal - Erro ao alterar o ícone padrão das notificações

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, push-notification, api

Estou tentando a algum tempo alterar o ícone padrão de notificações do OneSignal usando o Ionic, porém, até então, sem sucesso.

Segui os passos sugeridos na documentação oficial do Ionic, criei o arquivo `030_copy_android_notification_icons` no diretório `<app-root>/hooks/after_prepare`, e gerei um novo build, mas o ícone continuou com o sino padrão de notificações.

Tentei fazer a alteração de outra forma, seguindo a [documentação do próprio OnseSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons), mas recebo os seguintes erros quando tento *rodar* o app no meu celular com o comando `ionic cordova run android --device`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver esse problema, criei manualmente a pasta `xml` no diretório `<app-root>/platforms/android/res`, mas ao executar o comando novamente recebo outro erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse ponto, tive que criar a pasta `values` e dentro dela o arquivo `strings.xml` e ao executar o novamente comando `ionic cordova run android --device` recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a partir desse ponto não sei mais o que fazer. Já pesquisei aqui no Stack Overflow em português e também no gringo, mas não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar, até porque esse último erro é bastante genérico.

Já tentei também remover o android do cordova e adicionar novamente com os comandos `ionic cordova platform rm android` e `ionic cordova platform add android`.

Tentei também fazer o *downgrade* do cordova da versão 8.0.0 para 7.1.0, e nada.

**Obs.:** Apesar da mensagem `[OK] Your app has been deployed.` o aplicativo não é instalado no celular. Caso eu remova a pasta `<app-root>/platforms/android/res` tudo funciona normalmente, mas sem o ícone quepreciso inserir nas notificações.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de 1 semana muito longa consegui resolver esse empasse do ONESIGNAL

**1º Esqueça o método do site do IONIC, o código te um furo nesse IF**

```
if (fs.existsSync(srcfile) && fs.existsSync(destdir))
```

O fs.existsSync(destdir) retorna false, pois a pasta não existe na pasta raíz (/). Para ver o erro é só inserir alguns console.log no código e analisar o que está sendo feito.

**2º** Tome como base a instalação do IONIC Cloud Build dentro da documentação do Onesignal para alteração do ícone padrão ([link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons))

**3º** Entenda como funciona o RESOURCE-FILE do config.xml, que pertence a arquitetura do APACHE CORDOVA
(https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file)

**4º** Após você gerar a pasta de ícones com os nomes corretos e guardá-las dentro do seu projeto em alguma pasta específica e entender todos os passo anteriores, você pode colar esse código no seu CONFIG.XML

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
<resource-file src="resources/android/onesignal/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_onesignal_default.png" />
```

*Conclusão*: pelo que eu entendi houve uma mudança na arquitetura de geração de arquivos res/ dentro da plataforma do IONIC, assim gerando um desacordo entre as documentações. E também, podemos concluir que, o IONIC tem uma parcela de culpa pois o código tipo HOOK dentro da documentação não funciona na versão v1. (não sei se também buga no v1 e v3)